# Visual Studio Emulator for Android working but not listed in VS ('No devices available')

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

I wanted to test out the Visual Studio Emulator for Android, so I grabbed an example project (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/hello-jni-Android-790ab73d#content). Unfortunately, I can only select 'No devices available' respectively 'Android Virtual Device Manager" under Target Device.
When I start the emulator from the menu (Extras - Visual Studio Emulator for Android), it works fine - Visual Studio just somehow can't see it.
I tried to restart VS while the Emulator was running, but that also didn't help.

`adb devices -l` correctly lists the running emulator, btw.

Does somebody have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't get the message that the emulator only supports the debugging of x86 images - I changed the target platform to x86 and now it is working.

(Btw, I very quickly got the answer from a friendly Microsoft Employee after I sent them an email - Worth mentioning, I'd reckon)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same type of issue on my environment. I checked registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools" location and "Android SDK Tools" Key didn't exist. I created the Key and add String Value called Path and I provided Android SDK Tools path. It solved my issue. It is worth to shot.

Comment: Thanks for your input! The registry key was already present on my system, so that can't be my problem. It seems puzzling to me how a registry entry pointing to the android sdk can resolve an issue with the Microsoft VS Emulator for Android...